# Generate entities with mappers

Tags: zend-framework2

I am trying to find the best way to generate an enities, this is what I am doing at the moment.

I create an entity trough a mapper and a hydrator like this:

```
namespace Event\Model\Mapper;

use ZfcBase\Mapper\AbstractDbMapper;

class Event extends AbstractDbMapper
{
    protected $tableName  = 'events';

    public function findEventById($id)
    {
       $id = (int) $id;

       $select = $this->getSelect($this->tableName)
                      ->where(array('event_index' => $id));

       $eventEntity = $this->select($select)->current();  

     if($eventEntity){

        //Set Location Object
        $locationMapper = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('location_mapper');       
        $locationEntity = $locationMapper->findlocationById($eventEntity->getLocationIndex());          
        $eventEntity->setLocationIndex($locationEntity);

        //Set User Object
        $userMapper = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('user_mapper');
        $userEntity = $userMapper->findUserById($eventEntity->getEnteredBy());
        $eventEntity->setEnteredBy($userEntity);

        //Set Catalog Object
        $catalogMapper = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('catalog_mapper');
        $catalogEntity = $catalogMapper->findCatalogById($eventEntity->getCatalogIndex());
        $eventEntity->setCatalogIndex($catalogEntity);          
    }


    return $eventEntity;
   }
}
```

Now the problem with this approach is that when I call let say the User entity this entity has other entities attach to it so when I generate the Event entity by inserting the User entity my Event entity becomes very large and bulky, I dont want that I just want the first layer of the "gerontology tree".

So I was thinking on creating a EventEntityFactory where I can bind together the child entities of the Event enity, I was planning on doing a factory for this.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Thanks

Comment: A less bulky approach would be to write manual Queries, have only ONE Query and then map the Query-Result to your Objects using a custom Hydrator

Comment: Hi Sam, do you have an example I try to see how custom Hydrator works but couldn't figure out. Thanks

Comment: No code at hand, sorry. Can only point you into the direction :S But: are you experiencing actual speed problems with your current code? Remember to not optimize thing that do not NEED optimization!

Comment: Yes a bit, just when I call an entity that has many on his tree leg thanks for your recommendation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to use Virtual Proxies (with lazy loading):

http://phpmaster.com/intro-to-virtual-proxies-1/

http://phpmaster.com/intro-to-virtual-proxies-2/

Basically you would generate your entity, and replace any related entities with a light weight proxy object. this object would only load the related entity when required via lazy loading.

I've used this approach many times along with the Datamapper design pattern and it works very well.

Comment: Thanks Andrew let me check this out!