# How to hydrate objects that contain other objects

Tags: zend-framework2

How can I create an entity that has other entities set? I use mapper/hydrator and hydrator srategy like this example.

```
class AccountMapperFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        $dbAdapter = $serviceLocator->get('zfcuser_zend_db_adapter');

        $entity = new Account();

        $mapper = new AccountMapper();
        $mapper->setDbAdapter($dbAdapter);

        $hydrator = new AccountHydrator();
        $hydrator->addStrategy('orderId', new OrderStrategy());

        $mapper
            ->setEntityPrototype($entity)
            ->setHydrator($hydrator)
            ->setTableName($mapper->getTableName());

        return $mapper;
    }
}
```

Then i can call it like this

```
$this->AccountMapperFactory()->findById(1);
```

I get the account entity with an empty order entity, how can I create fill objects whats the way to do it?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For someone that is looking for the answer I found this two references.

[retrieving-every-field-of-a-database-row-as-object-in-zend-framework-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22275370/retrieving-every-field-of-a-database-row-as-object-in-zend-framework-2)

[generate-entities-with-mappers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14404524/generate-entities-with-mappers)